# Generate XML document using python

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine

i need to output my data in xml format like

```
<?xml version="1">
  <lang name='en'>
    <id>1</id>
  </lang>
```

how can i do that ?

Comment: What have you tried? Are the standard Python XML Libraries not available in App engine?

Answer (score 2):

Create a [template](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates):

```
<?xml version="1">
<lang name='en'>
    <id>{{ id }}</id>
</lang>
```

And render it in the handler:

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        id = 1
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/xml"
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/index.xml')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, {'id': id}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm) library. Example code:

```
from elementtree.ElementTree import Element

root_xml = Element("root")
root_xml.append(Element("test"))

# Get the output as xml:
output = etree.tostring(root_xml, pretty_print=True)
print output
```

Answer (score -2):

if figured out how to solve my problem:-
since app engine does not support standard Python XML Libraries i formatted a string by my self that output data as xml and that worked fine for me

```
xml = '<?xml version="1">\n<lang name="' + lang_name + '">\n   <ID>' + data + '</ID>\n</lang>'
self.response.write(xml)
```

Comment: Python is known to have great readability, but that code mangled it. Please consider the other answers.